# Are structs with preprocessor branched implementation an ODR violation?

Tags: c++, c, struct, one-definition-rule

In a project that uses both C and C++, a `.h` file contains a definition of a type. If that definition depends on whether the header is included by `c` or `cpp` files, am I violating the one definition rule?

```
// my_header.h
struct MyStruct
{
#ifdef __cplusplus
    std::size_t member; 
    int surprise; 
#else
    unsigned member; 
#endif
};
```

I know that ODR has to do with different translation units, but in "my case" won't different translation units end up having different implementations for a common struct? I've seen this in production code and initially I was wondering what is the linker doing in this case.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Not at all, as long as you remember to only use `surprise` in CPP compilers you should be fine. Only one of those conditionals will be compiled so the compiler will never see it.

Comment: @GillBates The project I'm working on has both C and C++ source files (both compilers are used). Oh, then you mean that there are 2 linkers as well so no prob ?

Comment: Does C++ actually care to specify what happens when parts of your program are written in another language? Or is this just undefined?

Comment: This looks like common sense violation. Why would you hide different things behind the same name?

Comment: ***WHY?!?!*** You're going to have a lot of *interesting* problems if you ever try passing such a structure between C and C++ code.  Especially if you're running 64-bit where `std::size_t` is not an `unsigned`.  `size_t` is `size_t` - it's most certainly not `unsigned`.  It may be *implemented* as `unsigned` *for some implementations*, but that's not the same.

Comment: @LorahAttkins no, that's most probably a single linker. Your question is completely justified, and I'm afraid the answer is "yes, that's a problem".

Comment: @Quentin thank you for being on point. I've already stated I've *seen* this in production code (am looking at it right now) but most comments go like "why do you want to do this.."

Comment: @LorahAttkins: Don't forget that in this context you are representing the author, so expect us to pretend that you are the author. If for no other reason than SO questions are designed to be reusable ;) Besides, you _did_ say "am _I_ violating the ODR"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you use one compiler (C or C++), you won't have a problem. It doesn't matter what extension the header files have.

But if you're linking together translation units from different languages, then yes you're violating the ODR.

Overall this just seems really error prone. I'd give the C++ type an entirely different name. You can use your macro to switch between the two, perhaps using the preprocessor around a `typedef`?

Comment: Right now I can't do more that complain to my supervisor and ask for 10+ year old code to be removed (and yes, there are two compilers in use :( )

Comment: @LorahAttkins: You should raise a major bug in your issue tracking system, if you think there's an ODR violation. Frankly, even if not, this is a really bad design and deserves a bug number. Maybe your bosses decide to leave it as it is, or maybe it can be fixed for the next big version.

Comment: I don't think it violates any ODR. There is an ODR for C and an ODR for C++, it does not violate those. There does not exist an ODR for mixed C and C++ projects.  It is just an area not covered by standards.

Answer (score 3):

There are two cases:

- All the translation units that include the header (for a given program) are compiled as the same language (C or C++):

  ==> No problems.
- Some translation units that include the header are translated as C, some are translated as C++.

  ==> ODR violation.

However, ODR violation is only "undefined behaviour", and actually, there isn't all that much which *is* defined in the standards about linking C and C++ together (except some vague suggestion "it ought to work").  In other words, if you are linking C and C++ together, you are probably depending on the details of your implementation anyway.

In general, if you are compiling 32-bit (so that `std::size_t` and `unsigned` are the same size), and provided that C++ does all the allocation, and provided that you never deal in arrays of these things in C, you will probably get away with it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I have a thought (hey, sorry, you asked): please don't write code that way. Okay I'll reserve the correct way to do this till the end. But as far as your question goes: yes, this will result in ODR violations if you use both a C and a C++ compiler as part of your build process. The actual file extension may be irrelevant (it may change defaults for the compiler, but your build system may explicitly specify the language the compiler). That said, this is a pretty bad idea and pretty unusual, because C is so close to being a proper subset of C++, that it would be much more common to simply write C code that can also build with a C++ compiler. And in the projects that have both C and C++ components, you would use a C++ compiler, and in projects that are pure C, you could still use that code. So, regardless of file extension, this is fine as long as a given project sticks to only one compiler.

```
// my_header.h
#ifdef __cplusplus
    constexpr bool is_cpp = true;
#else
    constexpr bool is_cpp = false;
#endif

struct cpp {
  std::size_t member;
  int surprise;
};

struct cc {
  unsigned member;
};

template <bool CPP>
struct MyStructImpl : private std::conditional_t<cpp, cc, CPP>
{
};

using MyStruct = MyStructImpl<is_cpp>;
```

This keeps as much code as possible in structs that are defined the same way and unconditionally regardless of macro options, and defers the macro related stuff to as late as possible. This is also a big win in terms of tooling and testing, e.g. you can run unit tests for both versions of your struct without recompiling.

Comment: I already mentioned that I've __seen__ this in production code. Never said I wrote it. I already give out all the things that look bad to me: ODR, linker. I'm asking as a plaintiff

Comment: Why not a simple `struct MyStruct { size_t member, int surprise };` for *both* C and C++?

Comment: @LorahAttkins Yes sorry certainly I did not mean to sound accusatory. You can tell your colleagues and such, that such conditional structs with macros are a bad idea independent of the whole C/C++ thing.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what violating the ODR means when you're linking multiple languages together; the *C++* standard has nothing to say about what `struct`s you can define in your *C* object files.  We are thus forced to answer in "assembly terms" (based on common implementations), in which case the answer (as has been given more eloquently already) is **wat**.